# Helmfile how change exist resource to another chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I want to move official-web this chart in sw-api chart template to independent chart,and move the files out off the sw-api's template
then use helmfile apply ,give me this error.

This is my error code

```
Error: Failed to render chart: exit status 1: 
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. 
Unable to continue with install: ConfigMap "official-web-config" in namespace "develop" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; 
annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "official-web": current value is "sw-api"
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the difficulty to understand your question. Could you please tell the exact steps that you've followed to get to this point? I'd reckon the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot. Also, could you please tell how the `google-kubernetes-engine` is related to this particular issue?

Comment: Hi Dawid , I put a new description below,  hope it can help you understand my situation.

Comment: Hi, I see the you've provided the information how it should look like. I do not think the update that you've posted should be an answer so I kindly ask you to delete it and to post it in the question. Also have you tried to delete the old resources and apply newly created structure?

Answer (score 0):

This my helm folder now

```
── sw-api
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── micros-worker
│   │   │   ├── configMap.yaml
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   └── hpa.yaml
│   │   └── official-web
│   │       ├── certificate.yaml
│   │       ├── configMap.yaml
│   │       ├── deployment.yaml
│   │       ├── hpa.yaml
│   │       ├── ingress.yaml
│   │       ├── ip.yaml
│   │       └── svc.yaml
│   ├── values-dev.yaml
├── sw-api-values.yaml.gotmpl
── swagger
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   └── svc.yaml
│   ├── values-dev.yaml
```

I  become like this

```
── official-web
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   ├── certificate.yaml
│   │   ├── configMap.yaml
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── hpa.yaml
│   │   ├── ingress.yaml
│   │   ├── ip.yaml
│   │   └── svc.yaml
│   ├── values-dev.yaml
├── official-web-values.yaml.gotmpl
├── sw-api
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   └── micros-worker
│   │       ├── configMap.yaml
│   │       ├── deployment.yaml
│   │       └── hpa.yaml
│   ├── values-dev.yaml
│   └── values-test.yaml
├── sw-api-values.yaml.gotmpl
```

And do helmfile apply command (in namespace "develop"):

```
helmfile -f helmfile.yaml --log-level=debug --debug -e dev apply
```

This error show before do hemlfile apply

```
Error: Failed to render chart: exit status 1: 
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. 
Unable to continue with install: ConfigMap "official-web-config" in namespace "develop" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; 
annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "official-web": current value is "sw-api"
```